Implement any rotation-invariant function on colored dodecahedrons
Each of a regular dodecahedron's 12 faces can be painted either red or blue. Your task is to implement a function \$f\$ that takes a painted dodecahedron (as 12 booleans, in whatever order and format is convenient) and outputs an identifier (a string or number). The exact function rule is unspecified, but it must be "exactly rotation-invariant" in the following sense: The permutations \$\sigma\$ for which \$f\$ satisfies the identity \$f(x_1,\dots,x_{12})=f(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(12)})\$ are exactly the 60 permutations that correspond to rotations of the dodecahedron.
Note that many rotation-invariant functions are also invariant under other permutations (like swapping all opposite faces), which disqualifies them. For every permutation \$\sigma\in S_{12}\$ that is not one of the 60 rotations, there must exist a coloring \$x\$ such that \$f(x)\ne f(\sigma x)\$.
It may be easier to meet the requirement by using more output values, so let's add a golf penalty of one byte per distinct possible output value. (Edit: maybe I should remove this in order to see a wider variety of strategies.)
Note: This is like my previous post but requiring a different permutation group and allowing more than two output values.

What class you mean?

You mean encouraging to share output for different weighted input? That seems silly

Edited to clarify. Also see the linked post.

I don't understand the "penalty for more output values". Surely the number of possible output values must be exactly equal to the number of possible colourings up to rotation?

@aeh5040 it must be at most that number (96), but it's possible with fewer. (The task of exactly classifying colored dodecaheda up to rotation is different and might also be a good golf challenge!)

Ruby, 89 bytes + 2 possible outputs
->n{i=1
("2%+@kgvv=#"*3).bytes.all?{|j|n!=((65|1<<j/12|1<<j%12)*4097>>i%3*4+(1&i+=1))&n}}

Try it online!
Saved 3 bytes using all?. This meant that i+=1 had to be moved as the true/false evaluation had to be the last in the loop. It could have gone at the beginning, but I decided to put it in parenthesis and use & instead of % (the byte count is the same either way.) Because i is incremented before it is used in this version, it must be initialised to an odd value instead of even, to avoid rewriting the magic string.
Ruby, 99 92 bytes + 2 possible outputs
->n{z=i=0
("2%+@kgvv=#"*3).bytes{|j|z&&=n!=((65|1<<j/12|1<<j%12)*4097>>i%3*4+i%2)&n
i+=1}
z}

Try it online!
A function taking a 12-bit binary number as input and returning true or false
Revised answer based on criteria without reflectional symmetry. If the  input corresponds to a set of four 1 bits on the faces of the dodecahedron arranged in a Z pattern (or part of such a set) returns false. Otherwise returns true.
The Z pattern has 2 fold rotational symmetry, therefore there are only 30 possible orientations of this pattern on the dodecahedron, and hence 30 possible sets of four 1 bits the input that return falsy. If we were to test for each orientation separately, then for each orientation of the Z pattern, there would be a 2-fold rotation of the inputs that leaves the output unchanged. Hence there are 60 possible rotations of the inputs that leave the output unchanged.
As a result of golfing, false is also returned for the following additional cases bringing the total to 229: all inputs with 0,1,or 2 1 bits (1+12+66=79); inputs with 3 1 bits corresponding to part of a Z with one of the four bits deleted (4*30=120).
Note that the fact that fragments of Z shapes also give false makes it easy to deduce the structure of the dodecahedron from the inputs. Any two 1 inputs will give false, but the number falses when a third  1 is added tells whether the first two correspond to faces that are opposite, adjacent or neither. If opposite, all 10 third inputs will give false. If adjacent, 6 third inputs will give false. If neither, 4 third inputs will give false. This is because the first two inputs form part of 5,3 or 2 Z shapes respectively, and none of the additional faces overlap.
Explanation
The face labelling system used in this answer is from my answer to this Steiner system question.  Note that opposite faces always have indices 6 apart, and the labelling has six fold symmetry because offsetting indices by 2 corresponds to rotating the dodecahedron 1/6 turn and flipping at the equator. Because we want to detect the Z shape but not its reflection (the S shape) we only consider offsetting indices by 4, which corresponds to a 1/3 rotation.
The ends of the Z shape are on opposite faces of the dodecahedron. They are therefore either both on equatorial faces or both on polar faces. These are listed below. Note that because the opposite faces are pentagons, there are 5 possible rotations per pair of opposite faces, generating 30 possible orientations of the Z shape.
The offsets to the remaining two faces of the Z shape for each possible rotation (5 for equatorial end faces and 5 for polar end faces) are listed in the diagram below and are stored in the magic string. They are decoded from the ascii code in j as j/12 and j%12 (because the order does not matter, careful selection of the encoding allows only printable characters to be used.) For even iterations, the expression (65|j<<j/12|1<<1%12)  generates the 4 bits for the equatorial case with end faces 0 and 6. 65 in binary is 1000001 and the expressions with j fill in the remaining  two bits. For odd iterations a rotated version of the polar case with end faces 11 and 5 is generated.
Equatorial 0&6  with 4&2 3&7 8&11 9&10 5&1
           4&10 with 8&6 etc       
           8&2  with 0&10 etc

Polar      3&9  with 6&4 8&7 11&10 0&1 5&2
           7&1  with 10&8 etc    
           11&5 with 2&0 etc
Polar offsets (subtract 3 from the above, take mod 12)
                     3&1 5&4 8&7 9&10 2&11  

   *       *       *
  / \     / \     / \
 *   * * *   * * *   * *   
 |11 |/ \| 7 |/ \| 3 |/ \
 *---*   *---*   *---*   *
 |10 | 8 | 6 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
 *   *---*   *---*   *---*
  \ /| 9 |\ /| 5 |\ /| 1 |
   * *   * * *   * * *   *
      \ /     \ /     \ / 
       *       *       *

Variable i keeps track of iterations 0 to 29. The expression above is multiplied by 4097 to duplicate it in bits 12 to 23 to allow for wrapping. For even iterations the result is rightshifted by i%3*4 to simulate a 1/3 rotation. For odd iteration the additional +i%2 imparts an additional shift of 1 (changing faces 0 and 6 to 11 and 5 as mentioned above, for example.)
This generates all 30 possible orientations of the Z shape in bits 0 to 11, in some cases with nonsense in higher bits. One way to clean this up would be to AND with 4095. But it is shorter to AND with the input n. This however means that when the result is compared with n matches are found not only for a complete Z shape but also for fragments of the Z shape, as described above.
Commented code
->n{z=i=0                   #take an input n. Set up a counter i. Set z to 0, a truthy value in Ruby.
("2%+@kgvv=#"*3).bytes{|j|  #triple the magic string making a string of length 30. Iterate 30 times.
z&&=n!=(                    #if the following expression equal to z, set z to false.
(65|1<<j/12|1<<j%12)*       #take 65=binary 1000001 representing the ends of the Z
                            #and use the magic string to fill in remaining 2 faces
4097>>i%3*4+i%2)&n          #make a duplicate in upper bits and shift right to rotate. 
                            #AND with n to remove bits beyond bit 11.
i+=1}                       #increment i
z}                          #return z true or false

Ruby, 32 bytes + 2 possible outputs, Invalid
The test used in a previous revision of this answer had reflectional symmetry and will therefore give the same output for a reflection of the inputs. Hence it is not valid. See edit history for details.

Cool! Does this not have a similar problem to l4m2's solution, though? If a coloring satisfies your criterion, then so does its reflection.

@karl Yes, a colouring and its reflection both satisfiy the criterion, since the test is reflectionally symmetrical. Based on discussion on l4m2's answer, it appears I may need to rethink. List of 2-colourings of dodecahedron at https://www.baumanneduard.ch/2FarbDode.htm It seems that all chiral sets of 4 faces have 2 fold rorational symmetry about an edge so each configuration only has 30 images under icosahedral rotational symmetry. If that is acceptable I can revise to 4 faces. It seems that fully asymmetrical configurations require 5 faces. I'll take this up on the chat at l4m2 's comments

Charcoal, 44 bytes, 2 outputs
⊞υθＦυＦＥ⪪”&＆L+gχa⟧«～¤j⧴”¹²⭆κ§ι℅μＦ¬№υκ⊞υκ⌊…⌈υ⁴

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a string of 12 0s and 1s. Explanation:
⊞υθＦυ

Collect rotations starting with the initial bitstring.
ＦＥ⪪”&＆L+gχa⟧«～¤j⧴”¹²⭆κ§ι℅μ

Generate two rotations of the current bitstring. One simply rotates the bits by 4, while the other one is more complex and I might not have got it correct, as I had to translate from the Wikipedia page to @LevelRiverSt's diagram and then to my diagram, but the theory is there.
Ｆ¬№υκ⊞υκ

Save this if this is a new rotation.
⌊…⌈υ⁴

A classification is to see if any rotations contains all 1s in the bits numbered 0-3 in the below diagram. Because I've generated all possible rotations, a rotation won't disrupt this, but a reflection would for asymmetric input e.g. 111100000000.
   *       *       *
  / \     / \     / \
 *   * * *   * * *   * *   
 |11 |/ \| 9 |/ \| 7 |/ \
 *---*   *---*   *---*   *
 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
 *   *---*   *---*   *---*
  \ /|10 |\ /| 8 |\ /| 6 |
   * *   * * *   * * *   *
      \ /     \ /     \ / 
       *       *       *


Hmm, what about the reflection that fixes 1,3 and swaps 0,2 (and therefore all other reflections, by composing this with rotations)?

@Karl Using the numbering on @LevelRiverSt's diagram, would 0,2,4,6 work?

Yeah, that's a "Z", so any reflection turns it into an "S", which prevents reflection-invariance (since detectZ(Z)!=detectZ(reflect(Z))). I'm still not sure about invariance under other permutations (that don't correspond to rotations or reflections).

@Karl I've updated my diagram and permutations to detect that "Z".

JavaScript (Node.js), 98 bytes + 2 possible outputs
Now incorrect. Waiting for a non-mirror color pattern
f=(x,i=0,g=s=>f([...s+90].map(c=>x['0x'+c-0]),i))=>x>'1,1,1,1'||++i<9&&g`1728a5b643`|g`4a1b532786`

Try it online!
Detects if some rotation cover [0,1,2]

Image outdated but 2<->7, 3<->6

I think I get it: $f$ checks whether there are three blue faces in a ")"-shaped configuration. This is rotationally invariant by construction, and it doesn't satisfy the reflection permutation identities because there are colorings that have a blue ")" but whose reflection does not. Is there an easy way to see that it doesn't satisfy any other permutation identities?

@Karl TIO shows that there's exactly 60 input of weight 3 that returns 1, so other permutating can't exist

wait it isn't correct, flipping 1-1, 0-2 still work.

I would upvote but I'm having difficulty understanding your diagram & code and would appreciate clearer explanation. According to OP you 're checking for 3 faces in ) configuration. Dodecahedron actually has 120 symmetries including rotation and reflection, but only 60 rotations. I'm not sure what issue you are referring to in your last comment but the ) configuration has reflectional symmetry and therefore gives 60 possible orientations as desired, not 120 (four pentagons in an S is the simplest configuration that looks different under refection and therefore makes things more complicated.)

@LevelRiverSt Actually I think the aim is to make the configuration potentially different under any permutation that's not a rotation (only one input has to give different outputs under a non-rotation permutation). In this case, a reflection fails because the ) has reflectional symmetry so that all inputs will give the same output as the reflected input.

@LevelRiverSt Edited at Dec 11 10:59:52Z that detects 4 faces to break symmetry

@Neil Seems every 3 face is symmetry so I now detect 4

I think a 4-face arrangement could work, but it looks like your {0,1,2,3} set has reflectional symmetry.

@Karl {0,1,2,3} in code, aka. {0,1,7,6} in pic, should flip to {0,1,7,5}

Oh I see. But doesn't {0,1,6,7} have a reflection symmetry too (fix 1,6 and swap 0,7)?

@Karl You're correct. Imagining dodecahedrons is hard

Do {0,2,3,8} work?

I don't think so - there is a reflection fixing 0,8 and swapping 2,3 (visible on the red labels). To avoid this kind of problem it has to be a chiral pattern like {1,0,8,6} (an "S" shape). I'm not sure if this guarantees correctness.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
